# Why doesn't ProvidePlugin produce a globally accessible variable?

Tags: webpack, popper.js

My Webpack config is relevantly as follows:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  Popper: 'popper.js'
})
```

In my `package.json` I have `"popper.js": "^1.14.4"`

When I run my app and type `Popper` into the browser console, I get:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined`

Why can't I access Popper globally as a variable?

Comment: because webpack doesn't actually do window.Popper = ..., it does some magic behind that points all the references for Popper to that package. It doesnt mean it exposes the variable globally as we are used to.